# Question regarding the dimension of a set of polynomials of degree n.

Tags: linear-algebra

so I primarily have two questions - one conceptual, the other just a question of mathematical notation. So for this question: [image: question]

It is asking me to determine whether it forms a basis for the given vector space. My first question focuses on the given set. Is $P_3(R)$ (where R is the set of real numbers, I don't know how to implement the specific symbol on here.) supposed to denote what it actually says in the parentheses: the set of polynomials of degree LESS than 3? I feel like this may be a typo or maybe I'm wrong. Looking at the set itself, it already contains polynomials of degree 3, so we can say off the bat that it cannot form a basis for $P_3$. My other question also focuses on the dimension of sets of polynomials. Is it always a given that it must contain n + 1 vectors for a polynomial set of degree n? I think I sort of understand this intuitively, but if anyone can further expand on why it would be useful as well.

Thank you so much in advance!

Answer (score 1):

It is the space of polynomials of degree less than or equal to 3. That space has dimension $4$, since the polynomials $1, x, x^2,x^3$ for a basis for it. In general, the space $\mathbb{P}_n$ of polynomials of degree less than or equal to $n$ has dimension $n+1$ (such a polynomial has $n+1$ coefficients). In your question, the answer is no, because no three polynomials can generate $\mathbb{P}_3$.